# C++: Calling a function on a returned class

Tags: c++

In the following code, my goal was to test the `outerFunction(myTest).setPrivateVar(5);` line.  I'm not sure why, but calling this function doesn't change the `privateVar` member of `myTest` to 5, but calling `cout << outerFunction(myTest).readPrivateVar` properly displays the value 200.  Can anybody explain why this is?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {
    private:
    int privateVar;

public:
    void setPrivateVar(int);
    int readPrivateVar();

};

void Test::setPrivateVar(int privateVarSet) {
    privateVar = privateVarSet;
}

int Test::readPrivateVar() {
    return privateVar;
}


Test outerFunction(Test passedTest) {
    return passedTest;
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {

    Test myTest;
    myTest.setPrivateVar(200);

    cout << myTest.readPrivateVar() << endl;

    outerFunction(myTest).setPrivateVar(5);
    cout << outerFunction(myTest).readPrivateVar() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
200  
200
```

Comment: `Test outerFunction(Test passedTest) {` takes a copy of `Test` and returns a copy. You should pass and return by reference `Test& outerFunction(Test& passedTest) {`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making copies here, both when you pass something into the function and when you return it:

```
Test outerFunction(Test passedTest) {
    return passedTest;
}
```

Modifications to `outerFunction(myTest)` affect the copy, not the original.

To get the semantics you seem to be after, you need to use references:

```
Test& outerFunction(Test& passedTest) {
    return passedTest;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I didn't think of that. I used reference when passing, and reference when returning, but never used both at the same time.